# Screen scale/size is right in iOS 8 but wrong in iOS 9 on same device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios9

I've recently updated Xcode to 7 so I could start developing against iOS 9.  Upon first launching my application, I noticed that the screen size/scale is off compared to how it looks on iOS 8, both on the iPhone 6 device.

Here is how it looks correct on iOS 8:

[image: image1]

Here is how it looks incorrect on iOS 9:

[image: image2]

If you also notice, both of those images are the same exact size.

Note how the AdMob banner has white space on the left/right, I'm assuming AdMob just knows to center it.  Also the big white space to the right of the table view and the button down on the bottom.

Also, when in iOS 8, and putting a break point in the main delegate method, the main window has a frame of (0 0; 320 568).  The layer on the window is also the same.

On the flip side, when in iOS 9, and putting a break point in the main delegate method, the main window has a frame of (0 0; 375 667).  The layer on the window is also the same.

That explains why the difference in the look of the app in iOS 8 vs. iOS 9, but I do not know why iOS 8 looks the way I want it to and iOS 9 doesn't.  Is there some setting that I'm missing?

EDIT:

I've also since figured out that the bounds of the mainScreen is different between when this runs in iOS 8 vs. iOS 9.  The screenBounds of the mainScreen is set to the same frame as up above, and I have no clue why it is different between the two iOS versions.

EDIT 2:

So I just created a brand new project and tested this out.  I do not get the same behavior as explained up above in my first edit.  When I view the mainScreen bounds, in both iOS 8 and iOS 9, it is (0,0;375,667);

I just cannot figure out what is causing this to happen so I can fix it.

EDIT 3:

After toying around quite a bit last night, it turns out that the launch images are causing this to happen.  If I remove the launch images of Default-568@2x.png from the list, then it displays properly.  Very odd that something like this can effect the scale.  I still didn't figure out how to solve this yet though because you have to have launch images or apple will reject the app, so I'm keeping this open until I have more time tonight to toy around with it.

Comment: Are you doing any layout in your `viewDidLoad`? If so, wait until `viewWillAppear`. Why not use a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` for your launch screen?

Comment: The launch screen size is exactly how the app's scale is determined.

Answer (score 3):

Are you testing on devices or simulators? If on device, your iOS 8 device might have Display Zoom enabled: Settings → Display & Brightness → Display Zoom. This would make an iPhone 6 (375 ✕ 667) think it’s an iPhone 5 (320 ✕ 568).

Comment: I am testing on my own device for iOS 8, and the simulators for iOS 8 and iOS 9.  The simulator and my own device for iOS 8 are both "correct" and look like the first screen shot.  The iOS 9 in the simulator looks wrong as in the screen shot.

I just checked the setting on my device and the display zoom is set to "Standard" and not "Zoomed".

That is why I'm wondering if there is some kind of setting in the code that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has always looked at features of your application to decide what screen sizes your app can handle, and simulated a screen size that it is sure your app can cope with.

For example, you have probably added a launchscreen image in 320 x 568 pixels. That tells iOS that you know about 4" devices; without that your app would run in a 320 x 480 screen. To support an iPhone 6, you would have had to add a 375 x 667 launch screen; without it iOS reports that you have only an iPhone 5 sized screen.

Now you are using the iOS 9 SDK. When you use that SDK Apple expects you to handle *any* screen size, so suddenly it reports the true screen size of 375 x 667 (414 x 736 on a 6+). You can't use hardcoded sizes anymore; you have to adapt your app to the screen bounds.